# Remove vertical spacing between two minipages

Tags: minipage, vertical-spacing, remove

I want to remove the vertical spacing between the top 2 minipages and the bottom 2 minipages.
Thanks for your help!
Regards,
chico (France)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bottom=0cm,top=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1mm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tiny

\fcolorbox{red}{white}{%
\begin{minipage}[b][\dimexpr 0.5\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr 0.75\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}%
\fcolorbox{red}{white}{%
\begin{minipage}[b][\dimexpr 0.5\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
}

\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{%
\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr 0.5\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr 0.4\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}%
\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{%
\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr 0.5\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr 0.6\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: blank line and `\nointerlineskip` before the second minipage

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Great answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a couple of ways:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bottom=0cm,top=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1mm}

\newcommand{\boxheight}[1]{%
  \dimexpr#1\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax
}
\newcommand{\boxwidth}[1]{%
  \dimexpr#1\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax
}

\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{red}{white}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b][\boxheight{0.5}][t]{\boxwidth{0.75}}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}}%
\fcolorbox{red}{white}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b][\boxheight{0.5}][t]{\boxwidth{0.25}}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{minipage}%
}\hrule height0pt
\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\boxheight{0.5}][t]{\boxwidth{0.4}}
  \lipsum[1][1-3]
  \end{minipage}}%
\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\boxheight{0.5}]{\boxwidth{0.6}}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

I shortened the box dimension specifications via handier macros. The trick is that `\hrule` will end the paragraph, but not add glue before and after it.

You can also replace `\hrule height 0pt with` \par\nointerlineskip`to avoid TeX adding`\lineskip` glue. The output will be the same.

[image]

A close up:

[image]